# Edit shown user groups in dropdown menu

Tags: php, magento

I'had the need of giving to my customer the ability to choose their user group. I've used a script found here in StackOverFlow (if anyone needs the link, here it is https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/239067/magento-2-customer-registration-with-customer-group/239071#239071 ):
The code I used is:

```php
<?php
$blockObj= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Nano\CommissionAgents\Block\CustomerGroups');
$groups = $blockObj->getCustomerGroup();
?>
<div class="field group_id required">
    <label for="group_id" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('I buy as:') ?></span></label>
    <div class="control">
        <select name="group_id">
            <?php foreach ($groups as $key => $data) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $data['value'] ?>"><?php echo $data['label'] ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

CustomerGroup.php

```php
<?php

namespace Nano\CommissionAgents\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection as CustomerGroup;

Class CustomerGroups extends Template {
    public $_customerGroup;
    public function __construct(
            CustomerGroup $customerGroup
    ) {
        $this->_customerGroup = $customerGroup;
    }

    public function getCustomerGroup() {
        $groups = $this->_customerGroup->toOptionArray();
        return $groups;
    }
}
```

SaveCustomerGroupId.php

```php
<?php

namespace Nano\CommissionAgents\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;

Class SaveCustomerGroupId implements ObserverInterface {
    public $_customerRepositoryInterface;
    public $_messageManager;
    public function __construct(
            CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface,
            ManagerInterface $messageManager
    ) {
        $this->_customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
        $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
       $accountController = $observer->getAccountController();
       $request = $accountController->getRequest();
       $group_id = $request->getParam('group_id');

       try {
           $customerId = $observer->getCustomer()->getId();
           $customer = $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customerId);
           $customer->setGroupId($group_id);
           $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->save($customer);

       } catch (Exception $e){
           $this->_messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('Something went wrong! Please try again.'));
       }
    }
}
```

And this works great, except that it obviously shows also the "NOT LOGGED IN" user groups. I would need that it just display the usergroups with id 1 (Customer) and 6 (Corporate) and not the one which id is 0 (NOT LOGGED IN).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update CustomerGroup.php and do the following:

- Create an array of ID's to remove
- Loop through the groups
- Do an array_search against the excluded groups
- Remove (using unset()) any ID's that match

```
namespace Nano\CommissionAgents\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection as CustomerGroup;

Class CustomerGroups extends Template {
    public $_customerGroup;
    public function __construct(
            CustomerGroup $customerGroup
    ) {
        $this->_customerGroup = $customerGroup;
    }

    public function getCustomerGroup() {
        $groups = $this->_customerGroup->toOptionArray();

        // Add group id's to this array you don't want to display in dropdown
        $excludeGroups = [0];

        foreach ($groups as $group) {
            // Check if the group is equal to any groups you want to exclude
            $groupKeyToRemove = array_search($group['value'], $excludeGroups);

            // remove the group from the array
            unset($groups[$groupKeyToRemove]);
        }

        // return the groups with only the values you want
        return $groups;
    }
}
```

Comment: Solved the problem with this code. Thank you a lot.